# Hilt Singleton for Android Service - ended up with 2 instances

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am using Hilt for dependency injection, and I wanted to start a singleton Android Service (DeviceConnectionService), and be able to access that Service object to do something to it

I observed 2 instances of DeviceConnectionService being created even though it was denoted as Singleton. Any idea or advice on this? Thanks in advance!

Following is my code setup:

**Android Library: DeviceLibrary**

**Android Service**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
@Singleton
public class DeviceConnectionService extends Service {
    @Inject
    public DeviceConnectionService () {
        Timber.d("DEVICE connection : " + hashCode());
    }
}
```

Another classes that wants to be injected with the Android Service - to do something:

```
@Singleton
public class Connection implements IHololensConnection {

    @Inject
    DeviceConnectionService connectionService;
    ...
}
```

**App**

**MainActivity.java**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceConnectionService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dagger doesn't start services, it just injects them once Android starts them. If you're observing that your Service is instantiated multiple times, that's unrelated to Hilt/Dagger/@Singleton: You'll need to ensure that your Service doesn't stop itself, and that nothing else stops it.

(This would be slightly different if your Service were instantiated exactly once, and *objects that your Service injects* were instantiated more times than you wanted. In that case you would need to put the @Singleton annotation on your binding for that class in a Module. However, that only applies to objects that Dagger creates, which excludes Service, Activity, or anything else marked with @AndroidEntryPoint.)